# Как называется сей дорожный знак?

Tags: грамотная-речь, названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как назвать этот колпак, стоящий на дороге (чаще всего ограждающий путь или замыкающий стоянку около здания)?

Answer (score 2):

Изображенный на фотографии знак относится к категории временных дорожных ограждений.
Он используется тогда, когда требуется закрыть проезд/проход в следующих ситуациях:
оформление ДТП;
поломка транспортных средств;
проведение спортивных, культурных, политических мероприятий;
спецоперации силовых структур, МЧС, в том числе, учебного характера;
блокировка зон, расположенных рядом с ремонтируемыми/строящимися объектами.

Называется это ограждение **«Солдатик»**. Изготавливается из высокопрочного полиэтилена, крепится на утяжеленную опору.

[Дорожное ограждение «Солдатик»](https://ros-znak.com/produktsiya/dorozhnoe-ograzhdenie-soldatik) (ПК «Росзнак»)
[Ограждение «Солдатик» тип 2 в компл. с подставкой](https://www.idn500.ru/fencing/ograzhdenie_dorozhnoe_soldatik/ograzhdenie_soldatik_tip_2_v_kompl_s_podstavkoy/) (ПК «Технология»)

Answer (score 1):

Можете назвать его *барьером*, *блокиратором* или *ограничителем* — как Вам больше понравится.